# Is there a full character set for Cisco IOS passwords?

Tags: passwords, cisco-router, password-generation

I need to set password generation rule for a large amount of Cisco IOS routers, and am trying to figure out which special characters are permitted.

The problem is that the only piece of cisco documentation I can find related to this is [extremely vague](https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/sec_usr_aaa/configuration/15-sy/sec-usr-aaa-15-sy-book/sec-aaa-comm-criteria-pwd.html)

> The password composition policy allows you to create passwords of any combination of upper and lowercase characters, numbers, and special characters that include “!”, “@”, “#”, “$”, “%”,“^”, “&”, “*”, “(“, and “)”.

This suggests that there are more permitted characters than are listed here, but I cannot find the full list anywhere.

[The Centrify documentation](https://docs.centrify.com/Content/Infrastructure/resources-add/svr-mgr-cisco-pwd-rules.htm) suggests a larger list of possible characters, but it is not the official cisco documentation, and thus I cannot be confident that there is no compatibility setting in Centrify allowing for a larger charset than Cisco alone.

Is there a more precise cisco specification somewhere that I missed?

Comment: Personally, I think this question would be on topic for Security StackExchange. I am interested in the answer for security reasons.